# Alternative of accessibilityLabel to be used by Appium for React Native apps

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

we have multiple React Native apps and we are using Appium web-driver to identify the elements easily by adding the accessibilityLabel so it doesn't matter what locale i'm using the app with but now we got many complains from the customer as the accessibilityLabel is being used by the iOS system to help handicapped users. For instance, Voice Over uses this and if you set some testing value to this, your handicapped users will suffer.

Also we cannot use byText as it is not optimal because of the localization, now our React Native development team ask us to provide an alternative for the accessibilityLabel , any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS in React Native you can use testID, for android as far as I know accessibilityLabel the only way.
So usually it would be something like that:

```
testID= {"ElementId"}
accessibilityLabel= {"ElementTextDesc"}
```

Comment: Hack with `accessibilityLabel` instead of `testID` on Android is not actual since `react-native@0.65.x` !!!

See changelog: https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#android-specific-9 ;

Commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/381fb395ad9d2d48717a5d082aaedbecdd804554 ;

Comment: @DAVID_ so we can safely use only `testID` for both platforms now?

Comment: found this also: [An end to the abuse of Accessibility IDs](https://dev.to/nextlevelbeard/an-end-to-the-abuse-of-accessibility-ids-5d2j)

Comment: right, feel free to use testID on Android